# how to validate an email address to this form: 234903284@student.uws.edu.au

Tags: php, regex

I'd like to know a regex that would validate:
an email address to this form: 234903284@student.uws.edu.au

couple issues:

"student." is optional and could be any word eg "teacher.".

"324234234" can be any alpha numeric characters (number, word, _ etc.)

the email must end in "uws.edu.au"

This is what I have so far:

```
/(\d*)@\w*\.uws\.edu\.au/
```

valid addresses:

me@uws.edu.au
234234324@student.uws.edu.au
theking@teacher.uws.edu.au

etc.

Thanks Guys

Comment: You have to escape the `.` else it matches anything.

Comment: What was unclear about the question? seems a bit vindictive to vote me down and yet not say why.

Comment: What about other characters that are valid in the first part of the email address? Like '$', '&', ''' and '#'

Comment: fine, removed that comment. please undo the negative vote if you would be so kind :)

Comment: Aim wide; make sure you have at least one `@` and one `.` and then do some *actual* validation by sending a confirmation email. Testing with complex regex is completely pointless without also confirming the address exists and is active.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said:

> Just tried /(\w*)@(\w*.)?uws.edu.au/ and that seemed to work. Any further suggestions are welcome – Jason 4 secs ago

Your regex will match `"@teacher.uws.edu.au"` (i.e. "name portion" omitted).

To fix this, you could use:

```
/(\w+)@(\w+\.)?uws\.edu\.au/
```

Which will require at least one character in the name portion, and at least one char before the dot (if there is a dot) in the subdomain spot.

Also (I think) that `\w` will *not* match `.` (and probably other chars that you care about in the name portion too), so `bob.jones@student.uws.edu.au` would fail to match.  The following would add the char `.`, `_`, and `-` into the "name" portion:

```
/([\w\._-]+)@(\w*\.)?uws\.edu\.au/
```

you could add any other chars you need in the same way.

NOTE: Matching email addresses *in general* a more complex thing than you might think (lots of strange things are *technically* allowed in email addresses.  [Here is an article on the subject](http://haacked.com/archive/2007/08/21/i-knew-how-to-validate-an-email-address-until-i.aspx) (There are many other sources of similar information available).

Answer (score 4):

Three thoughts:

- Change the initial `\d` to `\w` to match "word" characters [a-zA-Z0-9_] instead of just digits.
- Make the subdomain optional using `?`
- Use `+` instead of `*` when matching the username and subdomain. Otherwise `@.uws.edu.au` will validate.

Suggested:

```
/\w+@(\w+\.)?uws\.edu\.au/
```